# CodeIgniter URI Routing and empty segment

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

I now set uri routing in my codeigniter config like this

```
$route['user/:any'] = "users";
```

and everything works fine with request like this

```
http://localhost/user/1
```

but if i try request

```
http://localhost/user/
```

so uri segment is empty, i am getting error

```
404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found.
```

how to avoid this? I ve tried to use

```
$user = $this->uri->segment(2);
if (!isset($user)) redirect('/', 'refresh');
```

but this is not working.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the '1' in the second segment for?

Comment: I think `1`  can be only... administrator ;D

Comment: Just string now to test output, planning name/id

Comment: Still not working? Have you tried `$route['user'] = 'users';
$route['user/(:any)'] = 'users/index/$1'; ` ? What is `var_dump($slug); die();` in your **index** method in your controller **users** echoing when you access it like `http://something.com/user/2`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add another route such as:

```
$route['user'] = "users"
```

Comment: This is working, with **if (empty($user)) redirect('/', 'refresh');** perfectly, only minus is addition route

Answer (score 4):

build your functions in your controller instead of this:

```
public function index()
{
...
```

try something like this:

```
public function index($slug = '')
{

if ($slug = '') {
   // redirect code here
}
else {
   // if there is something in $slug then load this code
}
```

and maybe your routes should be something like:

```
$route['user'] = 'users';
$route['user/(:any)'] = 'users/index/$1';
```

Comment: Tried this **index($slug = '')**, isn't working because codeigniter uri routing only can get methord parameter as $this->uri->segment(2);

Comment: To get parameters for your method instead `$route['user/:any'] = "users";` try this: `$route['user/(:any)'] = 'user/index/$1';` as I suggested. WHat is the file name of your controller for users? user or users?

Comment: controller **users** :) tried **$route['user/(:any)'] = 'users/index/$1';** uri routing works fine, but without parameter still 404

Comment: if you try: `var_dump($slug); die();` as first thing after `public function index($slug = '') {` what happens? Are you shure that in browser you have links like: `http://something.com/user/2` and not something like `http://something.com/index.php/user/2` ?

Comment: After `http://something.com/user/2` there should be then the value echoed. How do you access this method via browser? What is your url? You can change your domain name if you don't want to reveal it.

Comment: Are you using constructor in your class? There should be a problem too. I mean something like: `function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->model('users_model');
 }` Do you use constructor?

Comment: Again there must be the parameter present if you use `$route['user/(:any)'] = 'users/index/$1';` Do you have set your route for users like this? What is var_dump output when you access it like: `http://something.com/user/2` in your browser?

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
$route['user:any'] = "users";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to fix the syntax, please try:

```
$route['user/(:any)'] = "users";
```

You need parentheses around the wildcard `(:any)`.

Reference: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html  see Examples

Comment: I thought the same thing, but after some testing, `:any` also works.  Although, it's definitively better to follow the documentation.

Comment: The CI documentation shows one example without parentheses.  I think that the parenthesis are needed if you are trying to capture the segment value to reuse in the new route.

Comment: You are right, you can't use the back-reference if you don't put parenthesis.  [CodeIgniter supports `:any`](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Router.php#L340), but doesn't automatically add parenthesis.

Comment: That makes sense, CI is probably relying on a regular expression parsing approach.